# What MVVM Framework (Silverlight) should I use?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm working on Silverlight, of course I use MVVM. I found many problems but I can create work-around solution for them (some of these solution is not elegant at all), now I think it's time to bring some framework to help me.

I need functions that listed below.

1. Dependency Injection
2. Navigation
3. Callback
4. Messaging
5. Bind event to Command
6. Testability

As I know, there are many Framework out there, such as, Jounce, MVVMLight and Prism. I want to know which framework is suitable for my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to dependency injection I'd rather use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

which greatly simplifies code. As for the rest of the functions , currently I'm working with MVVMLight and I haven't faced any problem (although I'm not familiar with Jounce and Prism)

Comment: Are there ViewModelLocator and Messaging in MVVMLight? (I know there's EventToCommand out there :) )

Comment: Of course there is ViewModelLocator and Messaging in MVVMLight , just navigate through http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/ to get a glimpse of what's included there

Comment: @Anonymous: yes they are. I share the @tchrikch opinion to use the MEF + MVVMLight. Both are simple (in the good way)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider the scale of the application. If it is a relatively small application that is unlikely to grow I would choose MVVMLight.

For a larger LOB application I would consider PRISM or Caliburn. I would also recommend reading blog posts by [John Papa](http://johnpapa.net/) and [Jeremy MIller](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/) on MVVM, Screens and Coordinators. Their ideas and insights helped enormously in a large scale Silverlight project I've built.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF Prism is great, in Silverlight Jounce is the best by far. Its is very well integrated with MEF , very lightweight, elegant and stable. It also provides nice implementation to support complex events workflow scenarios, VisualStateManager in ViewModel (love that one), validation, debugging and unit testing; Used it in some quite complex projects and was happy I chose it.